# Making large dataset available within a package but not as global variable

Tags: r

This is my first attempt at creating a package so I'm guessing it's a pretty basic question. Essentially I want to export the following functions from my package:

```
load_data <- function() {
  requireNamespace(XML, quietly = TRUE)
  xmlfile <- XML::xmlParse("//server/folder/file.xml")
  ps <<- XML::xmlToDataFrame(xmlfile, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
}

find_record <- function(search_string) {
  return(ps$Var1[ps$Var2 == search_string])
}

delete_record <- function(search_string) {
  ps <<- ps[ps$Var2 != search_string, ]
  return(TRUE)
}
```

But I don't want to create the global variable 'ps'. What's the right way to have a large dataset available to other functions inside a package?

Comment: Maybe the internal data section [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) will help...?

Comment: Thanks joran, that tells me how to save internal data in an Rda file but how do I then access that internal data in my find_record function? Do I need to have a load() command in each function to load that data?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, I've never done it myself. Wouldn't be too hard to try though...

Answer (score 1):

**If the data file is small enough to store in the package**

Your load function suggests that although the original data file is XML, it can be transformed to a data frame.  So convert to the data frame, then save that as an RData file in the data directory of your package.

**If the dataset is too big to store locally, and it's a private package**

Your question title hints that it's a big dataset, and that the original data resides on a server.  In this case, you are better off storing your data in a database, and using R's database access capabilities inside your function.

**If the dataset is too big to store locally, and it's a public package**

I suspect that this is beyond the scope of the question, but there are loads of R packages that provide access to online databases via some sort of web API.

Comment: Thanks Richie, I want to take option 1 (store the RData file in the package) but I would like the data.frame to be in memory so that when the user of the package calls either the find_record or delete_record function they **don't have to go to disk** to re-load the whole dataset. Essentially I guess I want the data.frame to be a global variable, but inside the package only. Can this be done?

Comment: Datasets stored in the `data` directory are "global" to the package, but they are designed to be read-only.  You can change them, but you'll be changing a copy, so you'll have to decide what happens after you delete a record.  For example, if you overwrite the RData file, then are you overwriting it in the user's installed copy of the package?  Or do you want a mechanism to delete the record for everyone?  In which case storing the data in the package is the wrong way to go.