# How should I pass a data frame between functions in a package, perhaps using a special environment

Tags: r

I have a data frame that I want to use, unmodified, in a number of functions in my package.

I could create a function that returns the data frame when required, e.g.

```
lookup <- function() return(data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),text=c("Alpha","Beta","Gamma")))}

test <- function() {
  print(lookup())
}
```

Or I could write a global variable

```
lookup <<- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),text=c("Alpha","Beta","Gamma"))

test <- function() {
  print(lookup)
}
```

Or I could create the data frame in my main function and pass it to every function that needs it.

```
main <- function() {
  lookup <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),text=c("Alpha","Beta","Gamma"))
  test(lookup)
}

test <- function(lookup) {
  print(lookup)
}
```

Option one doesn't feel right as I'm re-creating the data frame from scratch each time I call the function.

Option two is bad practice as a package shouldn't rely on global variables as the caller may be using that variable themselves.

Is option three the right way to do this and is just the way things work by design in a functional language?

Or is there a way where I don't need to pass the data frame to the called function? Some magic involving environments perhaps? i.e. Can I create the data frame in a special environment and then refer to that environment in the function without passing it?

Something like this:

```
main <- function() {
  lookup <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),text=c("Alpha","Beta","Gamma"))
  my_special_enviroment <- add(lookup)
  test()
}

test <- function() {
  print(my_special_environment.get(lookup))
}
```

Thanks

Note, I posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039804/making-large-dataset-available-within-a-package-but-not-as-global-variable) but that related to large data sets, not small ones as in this example.

Comment: Probably I don't understand what you want, but in his answer, Richie Cotton says "[...] then save that as an RData file in the **data** directory of your package".

Comment: Define the data frame in one of the .R files and it will always be available to the package.

Comment: @Pascal reloading the data from disk at each function call seems like a massive overhead that I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: I don't think it is doing this.

Comment: @Pascal sorry, I don't get it. Are you/Richie saying that any RData files in the data directory are always available in memory when the package runs?

Comment: OK, I just tested that and it does indeed work. When you load the package all .RData files are added to memory and available. Thanks @Pascal and Richard Scriven and sorry for being so slow to catch on!